# Unable to get MOTD's claimed package updates

Tags: apt, server, upgrade, 18.04, motd

Recently I've come across an issue with a discrepancy between the MOTD and output from `apt` or `apt-get`.
When I log in, my MOTD states that I have 13 packages to update, but regardless of what I try I can't seem to find the updates packages at all.
I've tried all of the following:

- `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt upgrade` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`
- `sudo apt full-upgrade` and `sudo apt-get full-upgrade`
- `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
- `sudo apt update -f` and `sudo apt-get update -f`
- `sudo apt autoremove` and `sudo apt-get autoremove`

All of these have simply spat out:
`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded`

**I haven't modified my MOTD**, and it appears to be updating as the processes, users logged in, disk use, and processor use change.
In addition, the files `/etc/motd.tail` and `/etc/motd.tail.old` appear to be missing entirely, so other 'fixes' online for issues like this seem to not apply or be exclusively for older versions of Ubuntu.

Any idea what could be causing this, and hopefully how to fix it?

Comment: MOTD typically updates only once per day, while apt actions can happen anytime and changes to the repos can happen anytime. If somebody wants to write an MOTD module that keeps apt information in sync (but doesn't consume a lot of resources), please feel free.

Comment: There is no `apt distro-upgrade`.